# SP Library that embeds an image with a link

Tags: 2013, custom-list, image-display

I am trying to make a library that you would just need to put the image and url in and it would create a hyperlinked image that will display on our site. I feel like I'm really close but I'm missing something.
I used these instructions here: [Adding an image link via calculated column on a list with HTML directory list solution](https://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2014/06/11/adding-an-image-link-via-calculated-column-on-a-list-with-html-directory-list-solution/)

Basically creating a calculated column which works great! But...I want to be able to put my own picture there. I tried editing the formula to this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Site URL]), "URL Missing", ("<a href="&[Site URL]&"target='_blank' alt='Open site in new window'><img src=[photo url column]' /></a>"))
```

But that doesn't do the trick. I'm not sure why it won't work. If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate the assistance!

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Comment: I'm on version 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "photo url column" is a column, so that you need to use the following formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Site URL]),"URL Missing",("<a href='"&[Site URL]&"' target='_blank' alt='Open site in new window'><img src='"&[photo url column]&"'/></a>"))
```